# Why using View Binding is changing the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-viewbinding

Actual Code:

My Main Activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        val rollButton = binding.rollButton
        rollButton.setOnClickListener { rollDice() }

        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    private fun rollDice() {
        val randomDiceRoll = Random.nextInt(6) + 1
        Toast.makeText(this, randomDiceRoll.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        binding.resultText.text = randomDiceRoll.toString()
    }
```

My XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/count"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/roll_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/roll" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Preview in android studio:

[image: Preview]

Actual layout in device:

[image: actual layout]

If I change `setContentView(binding.root)` to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`, the layout of Android Studio and the device become the same, but of course, the button doesn't work anymore...

Why does this happen? Why is `ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` changing the layout? How to fix this?

Thanks

GitHub Repo:
https://github.com/Wizard28082006/Dice_Roller

Comment: Did you use the given xml-Layout for both, databind and normal layout inflation?

Comment: @sebi0920 Yes, I used the same xml-layout for both.

Comment: It's because your `layout_height` is `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce But the preview in Android Studio shows that it is centered?

Comment: That's because the Preview wraps your view with a container that is centered, but your view itself is not centered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I change setContentView(binding.root) to setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), the layout of Android Studio and the device become the same

Most likely caused by how the `container` is not passed to the inflater if the view is inflated like this.

You could try the following instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
```

And

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.bind(findViewById(R.id.root))

        val rollButton = binding.rollButton
        rollButton.setOnClickListener { rollDice() }
```

Comment: Can you explain why the stems are not passed?

Comment: Well, it's never passed, is it? To find it, you'd have to do `findViewById(Window.ID_CONTENT` but nobody really does that.

Comment: I spent 6 hours trying to figure out `ActivityMainBinding.bind(findViewById(R.id.root))`, I honestly wish I could give you more points on this - thank you!

Comment: @Nefariis in retrospect, using `ActivityMainBinding.bind(findViewById(Window.ID_CONTENT).getChildAt(0)))` is technically more correct, mostly because that way you don't need to give an ID to the root container. I've been calling that `container` instead of `root` to stop having conflicts with `binding.getRoot()`.

Comment: doesnt this defeat the purpose of using view bindings

Comment: @LucaGuarro no? why would it

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding "In most cases, view binding replaces findViewById"

Comment: 1 findViewById replacing 17+ findViewByIds still sounds like a deal

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Isn't the layout inflated twice if you use the layout resource id instead of the binding object? Also, won't the listeners be installed to the wrong layout object? I'm referencing Sean McQuillan's findViewById vs ViewBinding article: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-view-binding-to-replace-findviewbyid-c83942471fc

Comment: @NathanMeade using `_Binding.bind()` will not instantiate the layout again, that's `.inflate()`.

Comment: Ah okay, yes - I was using `.inflate()`. Good to know! Thanks @EpicPandaForce

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should set android:layout_height as match_parent in your linearlayout and align inner views in it.

Comment: I got a [working code](https://hasteb.in/dixetazi.xml) from the changes you said me to make, this one looks the same across android studio and my device... But I used `android:gravity="center_vertical"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" to make it work... Can you explain why did this happen?

Comment: @Wizard28 I experienced the same result when doing what you did. Sandeep Patil's answer does a good job explaining why this occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Since the screenshots suggest that the question comes from [the Udacity course on Andorid](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-kotlin-developer-nanodegree--nd940), there is a good explanation on the [course knowledge hu](https://knowledge.udacity.com/questions/396380)b (link accessible only to the course users). In short, the explanation is the two things mentioned in [the `setContentView` docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and [the `ViewBinding` docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

First is that when using `setContentView` the

> layout parameters of the specified view are ignored

and the drawback of `ViewBinding` is

> it doesn't support layout variables or layout expressions, so it can't
> be used to declare dynamic UI content straight from XML layout files

Comment: This should be higher up. This explains what the problem actually is. Simply changing the layout_gravity to gravity doesn't explain what the problem is and why this issue is occurring. Thank you Sandeep.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between `android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity`:

- `android:gravity` sets the gravity of the **View Content** (or child in case it was applied on a `ViewGroup`).
- meanwhile `android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the **View** it is applied on, **relative to its parent**.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `android:gravity = "center"` to LinearLayout solves the problem.