# View binding not working, what did I miss?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding, android-viewbinder

I am following the Android Kotlin course on Udacity which suggested to use viewbinding instead of `findViewById()`. However, I am trying to use it and the text in my application does not update. I've tried to rebuild the app and I have added `buildFeatures {viewBinding true}` in the build.gradle(:app).

My viewbinding text change is really simple:

```
val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
binding.rollButton.text = "Let's roll"
```

Is there something I missed about viewbinding?

Comment: Did you `setContentView(binding.root)`?

Comment: @Zain hmm that does work! But it destroys the layout gravity... One problem creates another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before using views in the activity you have to inflate view as Content View for the current activity

```
val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
binding.rollButton.text = "Let's roll"
```

Comment: It works, but the ```setContentView(binding.root)``` changes the <LinearLayout> gravity. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Edit: I've found a solution for anyone who ever needs help with this too: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61695769/why-using-view-binding-is-changing-the-layout)